# Grepping through logs to get user, path

Tags: python, regex, grep

I have set up some logging to track user behavior. Here is what a sample line in my log file looks like:

```
[INFO] User david@gmail.net DELETE /api/upitem/126926
```

How would I get all lines where the username `david@gmail.com` is in the line AND the url `/api/upitem/` is in the url?

Something along the lines of

```
`grep 'david@gmail.com' ./file.log | grep '\/api\/upitem\/ ./file.log1`
```

Would would be the best way to do this log search/analysis?

Comment: Why you have tagged `python` to this question?

Comment: Do you want a python or grep solution?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham either one would be fine. I'm using python/django for the application so could use that or grep.

Comment: Well using python a simple `if  "david@gmail.net" in line and "/api/upitem/12692" in line` would do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a single grep command with `-P` parameter enabled.

```
grep -P '^(?=.*\bdavid@gmail\.com\b)(?=.*/api/upitem/)' ./file.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using awk, like this:

```
cat file.log | awk '{ if ($3=="david@gmail.net" && $5 ~ /api\/upitem/) print }'
```